# Set PHP configuration settings in application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework

I forget how I can set PHP configuration settings from the application.ini of Zend Framework.

I want to set max_execution_time variable.

Help me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use application.ini to set any of the settings that can be set using the [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set) directive, there is a [list of them here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

In your case you are replacing the [set_time_limit()](https://www.php.net/set_time_limit) function which changes [max_execution_time.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

So you want to put this into your application.ini

```
phpSettings.max_execution_time = 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your application.ini

```
phpSettings.max_execution_time = 30;
```